# A crash reports from Apple I can't duplicate or find

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a crash I can not duplicate, but Apple runs into on login. None of my debug runs or TestFlight user have seen any crashes.
The crash reports from Apple seem. to point to a Swift wrap/unwrap issue

```
Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104a5b638
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [14192]
Triggered by Thread: 0

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 ActivuGenesis 0x0000000104a5b638 specialized loginViewController.viewDidAppear(_:) + 849464 (loginViewController.swift:434)
```

The line in viewDidAppear (crash lineis 434 is as follow)

```
guard let HostNameTest = detailStoreData?.ServerData[currentIndex].HostName else {
self.showAlertError(msg: "Host IP Not Valid")
return
}
```

I would expect to get a message and return, not crash.
I also tried (crash line follows)

```
  if let HostNameTest2 = detailStoreData?.ServerData[currentIndex].HostName {
    ServerAddressText.text = HostNameTest2
    tempIpAddress = HostNameTest2
  } else {
    self.showAlertError(msg: "Host IP Not Valid")
    return
  }
```

Some PO info with the value I see when I debug is

```
(lldb) po currentIndex
0

(lldb) po detailStoreData?.ServerData[currentIndex].HostName
▿ Optional<String>
- some : "3.217.58.75:59089"
```

I don't understand what is going on since I can't see myself - and I miss something? Do not understand why this crashes - Help.

Comment: fwiw; Apple docs say that a trap 5 means; "Swift uses memory safety techniques to catch programming errors early. If the Swift runtime encounters a programming error, the runtime catches the error and intentionally crashes the app. "

Comment: OK that may be true but the trace points at line which does not seem to be the main reason - so not very helpful. I have over a dozen user running same binary in TestFlight and not one once has had this or any crash - very frustrating

Comment: what is the data structure and data you're expecting in it?

Comment: I am expecting optional Strings which I convert to plain lets (via guard or if let ...) This always work in xcode 12.x and TestFlight and if the line Apple crash is correct I don't know why I just don't see error message and return.

Comment: data class lie this - class ServerData: NSObject, NSCoding {

    struct Keys {
        static let ServerName = "name1"  
        static let HostName = "name2" //: String
        static let Port = "443" as String
        static let UserName = "name3"
        static let Password = "name4"
        static let SSLon = "true"
    }
    
    private var _ServerName = "" //: String
    private var _HostName = "" //: String
    private var _Port = ""
    private var _UserName = ""
    private var _Password = ""//: String
    private var _SSLon = "true"

Comment: static? Are you sure? you can't access a static from an instance, only the type itself. at least I thought so.

Comment: I not sure about anything anymore but in all my case I am able to read value from my login controller in the viewDidAppear with the following code - guard let HostNameTest = detailStoreData?.ServerData[currentIndex].HostName else {
self.showAlertError(msg: "Host IP Not Valid")
return
} // and this works in Xcode and TestFlight but not with Apple review - I am lost why ? still hoping to find some clue why this crashes.

Comment: It looks like `ServerData` is an array. Are you sure that `currentIndex` is a valid index for that array?